# How to sum numbers which are strings in a column in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Here is a sample of my dataframe:

| personUID | lr | diagnosis |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `1234` | `65.1 63.38957151969269 90.221` | `ICD10_R99` |

When running the following command to sum the values in `lr`:

```
TotalRaw['lr_y'] = [
    sum(int(x) for x in string.split()) for string in TotalRaw['lr_y']
]
```

I receive the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '63.38957151969269'
```

The values in `lr` are strings as I had to convert them from float to strings in order to use `group_by`. Now I can't convert them back to strings nor can I use `string.split()`, any tips on how to resolve these errors?

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
TotalRaw['lr_y'] = [sum(int(x) for x in string.split()) for string in TotalRaw['lr_y']]
```

To:

```
TotalRaw['lr_y'] = [sum(float(x) for x in string.split()) for string in TotalRaw['lr_y']]
```